# SQL returning duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables -

**TimeLogs**

```
ID
UserID
JobID
TimeTaken
JobPhase
```

**MaterialsForJob**

```
ID
StockID
JobID
UserID
Quantity
```

**Stock**

```
ID
Name
CostPrice
```

The following query is returning duplicate rows, because there is more than one stock item allocated to the job and more than one phase (tl.Phase). My question is, how can I return just 1 row with sum's? By adding SUM() as it stands, the values returned would be wrong.

```
SELECT 
    TimeTaken as 'HoursSold', s.CostPrice * mfj.Quantity as 'StockCost'
FROM 
    TimeLogs tl
LEFT JOIN 
    MaterialsForJob mfj ON mfj.JobID = tl.JobID AND mfj.UserID = tl.UserID
INNER JOIN 
    Stock s ON s.ID = mfj.StockID
WHERE 
    tl.UserID = 10000 AND
    tl.DateEntry BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, '11/07/2013'), 0) 
                     AND DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, '11/07/2013'), 6)
```

At the moment, the above query returns -

[image: Screenshot of invalid data]

However, it should show -

```
19570633502 - 30.00
```

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Is ``mfj.UserID`` missing from your table definitions?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Added to MaterialsForJob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query with SUM and DISTINCT. This should get you the right result :

```
SELECT t1.JobID AS JID, SUM(DISTINCT(TimeTaken)) as 'HoursSold', SUM(DISTINCT(s.CostPrice * mfj.Quantity)) as 'TotalStockCost'
FROM TimeLogs tl
LEFT JOIN MaterialsForJob mfj on mfj.JobID = tl.JobID and mfj.UserID = tl.UserID
INNER JOIN Stock s on s.ID = mfj.StockID
WHERE 
    tl.UserID = 10000 and 
    tl.DateEntry between dateadd(wk, datediff(wk,0,'11/07/2013'), 0) and
    dateadd(wk, datediff(wk,0,'11/07/2013'), 6)
GROUP BY JID
```

Comment: This sort of works. It returns 2 rows, one for each tl.PhaseID. The stock cost is correct for both rows. However, ideally the HoursSold needs to be SUM() as well, so there is one row.

Comment: The HoursSold value is now correct, but the TotalStockCost is £60. It should be £30. The stock is assigned to the Job, which has multiple phases (of which there are 2 in this case), hence why it is £60. Not sure how to resolve this one! Cheers

Comment: Resolved the above by adding - SUM(DISTINCT(s.CostPrice * mfj.Quantity)).

Comment: Haha ! We got it almost at the same time. I have forgot the second DISTINCT. Good catch :).